# Slide in "read more" function without JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

is it possible to create a "read more" button that works like this:

The button will be a photo (I do not have this problem), the content is under the photo (Here, so far, I did it on the position: absolute principle, but unfortunately after showing the content, the rest of the page is not pushed down, and the text itself is above the next div ' ami). When clicked, the text comes out from under the photo, pushing the rest of the containers. When you click again, the text goes back up, hiding under the photo.

The toggle function between display: none and display: block or visible etc. is unfortunately out of the question as the content has to slide downhill.

It is important to me not to use jQuery.

If I did not explain something well, I will answer the questions, Martin

Comment: Its completely possible. However, we will need to see the html and script in the question with specificity as to which part of your code you're having trouble with

Comment: I have included my code beloe

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS only, here is an example:

The idea is to make a hidden checkbox with unique `ID` just before your text area, then create a label with `for` attribute and put that checkbox `ID` , finally with CSS check that checkbox is checked or not , if it checked add specific style to it's next element like that `#showMore:checked + .someText` , the symbol `+` means apply this style to the next `.someText` class only and in this case this class must be just after the checkbox and inside the same parent, while symbol `~` means apply this style to all `.theButton` classes that are siblings of the same parent.

```css
.someText{
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #444;
}

.theButton{
  background: #444;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  margin:10px auto;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
}

.theButton:after{
  content:"Read More";
}

#showMore:checked + .someText{
  height:100%;
}

#showMore:checked ~ .theButton:after{
 content:"Read Less";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="showMore" hidden />
<div class="someText">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</div>
<label class="theButton" for="showMore"></label>
```

Comment: Great, this works even without JS activated! It has just one big problem: It isn't accessible. The label may be read by assistive technology, but it doesn't convey in any way that it is clickable. That's why we have [WAI](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility). For initially learning about web-accessibility, I recommend [MDN's article about _Accessibility_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility).

Comment: Unfortunately i want my text to slide down from behind the "label" in your case (The label will be a photo that when clicked, triggers the text to go down and show up). I can't make it work your way :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to hide and show the text while pushing the content down (and having hard-coded heights is okay) here is an option based on your code. This uses the checkbox approach similar to the one by [@Ahmed Tag Amer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9765951/ahmed-tag-amer) with a fix for accessibility (opacity/position instead of display: hidden) and changes for element order.

I used the `<input type="checkbox">` and `<label>` to determine if the element is shown or hidden (not checked or checked input attribute) and positioned elements in to their parent with `z-index values`.

*Note: I have not checked this approach with browsers for compatibility.*

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 0;
}
#firstButtonCheck {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
#firstButtonCheck ~ .firstContent {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: margin-top 1s ease-out, max-height 1s ease-out;
}
.firstButton {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#firstButtonCheck:checked ~ .firstContent {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: margin-top 1s ease-out, max-height 1s ease-out;
}


#secondButtonCheck {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
#secondButtonCheck ~ .secondContent {
    background-color: grey;
    margin-top: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: margin-top 1s ease-out, max-height 1s ease-out;
}
.secondButton {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#secondButtonCheck:checked ~ .secondContent {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: margin-top 1s ease-out, max-height 1s ease-out;
}
.secondContent {
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="firstButtonCheck" />
    <label class="firstButton" for="firstButtonCheck">Picture Here</label>
    <div class="firstContent">
        <h1>First Content</h1>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.   </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secondButtonCheck" />
    <label class="secondButton" for="secondButtonCheck">Picture Here</label>
    <div class="secondContent">
        <h1>Second Content</h1>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.   </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But If i don't want specific height and width, but the text inside "content" will give the dimensions, this way won't work?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i imagined it. You can copy this code, it's complete. Unfortunately, the content of first container isn't pushing down the second container but covering it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    
    .first {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .firstButton {
        position: absolute;
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .firstButton:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .firstContent {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        z-index: 99;
        background-color: yellow;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .firstContentShow {
        top: 500px;
    }
    
    .second {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .secondButton {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: green;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 98;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="firstButton" onclick="showFirstContent()"></div>
        <div class="firstContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="secondButton"></div>
        <div class="secondContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    function showFirstContent() {
        var content = document.querySelector(".firstContent");
        content.classList.toggle("firstContentShow");
    }
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```